# large data on chart SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am creating a report that shows client ticket status on a Chart control in SSRS. The problem is, when the number of clients are less, data fits perfectly on the chart but when the number of client records exceeds 20, chart tries to fit everything on it and the data is not properly readable.

I want to split my data in such a way if the number of records exceeds the maximum limit of the chart it splits into two.

Comment: What kind of chart are you using? Bar? Line? Pie?

Comment: Can explain a bit more what you mean by "it splits in two" - do you mean you want it to carry onto a new page, or do you want to insert a scale break? Scale breaks can be added in the chart axis properties.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nathan. But I have resolved the problem by adding the Chart into Tablix control and then adding a Row Group = RowNumber ( Nothing ) Mod 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the Chart in a Tablix object. I would add a Tablix and associate it with the same dataset as the chart. I would delete all the columns bar one, and delete the Header and Footer rows. I would make the Details Row not Visible.

I would add a Row Group on a calculation to group by row number in groups of 20 e.g.

`= RowNumber ( Nothing ) Mod 20`

For the Group Header Row, I would resize it to fit the chart, then cut the Chart and paste it inside the Group Header row.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I managed to split my chart depending upon the number of records. Really appreciate your help